# Bind & Unbind... how to bind again when this function finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, unbind

http://jsfiddle.net/3NRsd/

```
var foo =  $("div").bind("click", function() {
    $("div").animate({"height" : "500px"}, 2000);
    $("div").animate({"height" : "50px"}, 2000);
    $("div").unbind();
    });
```

Comment: Do you mean, `$(this).unbind("click");` ? I Don't understand what you're after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
function handler() {
    $(this)
     .unbind()
     .animate({"height" : "500px"}, 2000);
     .animate({"height" : "50px"}, 2000, function(){
         $(this).click(handler); // <- gets called once the animation finishes
     });
}

$('div').click(handler);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3NRsd/6/)

Comment: Pleeeeease cache `$(this)`, or even better, do it on a chain. ;)

Comment: @DarthJDG - Can you explain what your comment means or post a link... :)

Comment: @DarthJDG: Right, chaining is better. Regarding caching `this`: Yes, it is an overhead but a small one and there are not too many calls in this function to jQuery. And besides that, performance optimization should be done after the code works ;)

Comment: @El Ronnoco: If you have a look at the code in the answer now, that's exactly what I meant by chaining jQuery methods. Previously there were multiple `$(this).method()` calls, which would create a separate jQuery object from `this` 3 times, which is unnecessary.

Comment: @ElRonnoco: Every function call introduces some overhead. `$(this)` basically calls jQuery every time and returns a new jQuery object. While this might have some impact if you call it every often, calling it a couple of times should be fine. You can see what jQuery is doing when it is passed a DOM element (https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L92) and it is not that much. It **is** better to cache it (or chaining) in terms of coding style (just looks cleaner) but certainly not because of performance.

Comment: @I2aelba: your code is unformated and it is not clear what you want. Everything that should be run after the animation has to go in the callback.

Answer (score 2):

You can rebind it in a callback from the animate function:

http://jsfiddle.net/3NRsd/8/